# How to display free disk space on cifs mount on linux command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, disk-space-utilization, cifs, samba4

In case there's any distinction between OS and shell necessary, I want to run the command on Ubuntu 14.04 with Linux 3.13 in GNU bash 4.3.11. `mount.cifs`'s version is 6.0 using smb2 protocol.
After mounting a share with `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=auser,uid=4322,gid=4322,rw //1.2.3.4/a_shared /mnt/a_share` I'd like to be able to monitor the free space on the share e.g. with `du`. The actual space on the device providing the share shouldn't matter, quotas should be respected. The result should reveal the same as the properties dialog in `nautilus`.

`df` doesn't include cifs mounts. I didn't have any further ideas.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and why it's not giving you the information you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I'd try:

1. `df -a`.
2. `df /mnt/a_share`.
3. `stat -f /mnt/a_share`.

Comment: So one has to believe that 1. cifs is a dummy filesystem (no wonder such a statement causes trouble if it written without any definition or reference) and that 2. the cifs mountpoint is a `FILE`, otherwise the man page wouldn't make any sense (as there's no accessible file on which a cifs can reside)